# Rewrite with redirect in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Original URL 1 - www.mysite.com/gallery-category.php?gallname=garments&GalleryID=10 
SEF URL 1 - http://www.mysite.com/photos-garments~10.html

Original URL 2 - www.mysite.com/gallery-category.php?gallname=furniture&GalleryID=20 
SEF URL 2 - http://www.mysite.com/photos-furniture~20.html

Original URL 3 - www.mysite.com/gallery-category.php?gallname=plastics&GalleryID=30 
SEF URL 3 - http://www.mysite.com/photos-plastics~30.html

To get this SEF URL, I wrote RewriteRule in .htaccess as

```
RewriteRule ^photos-(.+)~(.+).html gallery-catagory.php?gallname=$1&GalleryID=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [nc]
```

But now I want to redirect ONLY one particular URL to be redirected to another page.

i.e ONLY the http://www.mysite.com/photos-plastics~30.html to be redirect to http://www.mysite.com/plasticphotos.html the other 2 original URL's to be same page

I tried below Redirect URL, it is working but it redirect with the query string in browser - http://www.mysite.com/plasticphotos.html?gallname=plastics&GalleryID=30

Redirect URL

```
Redirect /photos-plastics~30.html http://www.mysite.com/plasticphotos.html
```

The output URL suppose to be - http://www.mysite.com/plasticphotos.html

Please help me to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect appends the query string automatically. If you don't want a query string, try this RewriteRule:

RewriteRule photos-plastics~30.html http://www.mysite.com/plasticphotos.html? [L]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be happening because you have a mod_rewrite rule that rewrites `^photos-(.+)~(.+).html` to `gallery-catagory.php?gallname=$1&GalleryID=$2` **and** you have a mod_alias directive that redirects `photos-plastics~30.html` to `/plasticphotos.html`. This isn't a query string issue because the query string is *being appended by your mod_rewrite rule*. This is because mod_rewrite and mod_alias directives are being applied to the same URI at different parts of the URL-file mapping processing pipeline. That means a rewrite rule is mangling the the URI and a redirect directing flags it for a redirect, so you end up with a frankenstein URI with its of both directives.

Whenever you mix mod_rewrite and mod_alias, you *have to be sure they don't interfere with each other*. Both modules get applied at different points of the processing pipeline. To ensure they don't screw each other up, just stick with mod_rewrite since you are already using it for internal rewrites. Add this rule **above your current rules**:

```
RewriteRule ^photos-plastics~30.html$ /plasticphotos.html [L,R=301]
```